# CreateProcess() in a client server application in windows

Tags: c++, c, sockets, threadpool, createprocess

I am working on a UDP client-server application where one server is supposed to handle 40 clients which could all be logged on at once.

Now in UNIX, such issues are resolved by using the `fork` function which basically creates a child process to deal with the client and leaves the server to accept new connections.

I searched on the internet and found out that `fork` is not available in windows, however `CreateProcess` could be used.

My previous research also introduced me to thread pools. So now I've two questions:

1. Could I acheive the functionality of `fork()` by using `CreateProcess()` in Windows?
2. If this is possible, what should I go for: thread pools or creating multiple processes?

Comment: [This Stack Overflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651181/for-a-client-server-program-what-is-the-best-approach-to-receive-multiple-clien) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Short answer is no, there is nothing like `fork()` in the Win32 API, but it should be possible to implement it since CygWin provide a fully featured fork() on Windows. But you don't seem to actually need `fork()`for your application.

**2.** Actually your options are :

- Create at least one thread/process for each client/connexion
- Create only one thread/process for all client/connexion (using an event-driven approach as instance)
- Mix the two above

The best approach depends on your application but for handling a maximum of only 40 simultaneous client, you can very well have one thread per client.

You could use the [POSIX standard thread library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) `pthread` to create and manipulate threads. This` library is standard in all POSIX-conformant OS (GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, BSD,  etc.) and has been ported to [Windows](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/). So this approach would allow you to have a very nice portability.

Although if you want to use the Win32 API, you should take a look at [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In linux fork function is used to create new process. Also for each process, there are different virtual memory space. For threads, only one common virtual memory is there. Also the the fork API can simulate in Windows (upto some extent) using the native API RtlCloneUserProcess.